# Two forms for class primary constructors

Tags: c#

I am trying the new class primary constructors feature.

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors) show usage like this:

```cs
public class C1(int x) {
  int X=x;
  int F() => X +1; 
}
```

which sharplab shows opens into:

```cs
public class C1
{
    private int X;

    public C1(int x)
    {
        X = x;
        base..ctor();
    }

    private int F()
    {
        return X + 1;
    }
}
```

However playing around I saw this also works:

```cs
public class C2(int X) { 
  int F() => X +1; 
}
```

which is obviously a nicer shorter syntax, and opens to:

```cs
public class C2
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private int <X>PC__BackingField;

    public C2(int X)
    {
        <X>PC__BackingField = X;
        base..ctor();
    }

    private int F()
    {
        return <X>PC__BackingField + 1;
    }
}
```

I am confused as to why the second form is not documented ? is it wrong in some way ? is there a practical difference between the two ?

Comment: [It is documented though.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors#create-mutable-state)

Comment: where ? that still shows the fields defined in the class

Comment: Please see the difference between C1 and C2, C2 does not have X defined separately

Comment: Okay so I did not misunderstand. The "Create mutable state" section does document this. Quote: "In the previous example, the primary constructor properties are accessed in a method. Therefore the compiler creates hidden fields to represent each parameter. The following code shows approximately what the compiler generates. [...]". Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hmm but the example there still defines the variables (Magnitude etc) explicitly

Comment: And why does that matter? It doesn't invalidate what the documentation says. You can delete them if you want. The key point is that the constructor parameters are used in an instance method (i.e. `Translate`). *That creates hidden fields*.

Comment: So your answer is the second form is valid and there is no need to explicitly declare the fields

Comment: This is too awkward. For instance, if I need a `squareX` field, how will you do with the second form?

Comment: Shingo can't I just add a property ?

Comment: What if it must be a field?

Comment: I can't see that case but sure there may be cases where the first form is preferable but surprised the second form which seems to be better in most cases is not shown

Comment: I don't see the difference? Putting a parameter in the primary ctor implicitly declares a field. If the compiler can remove the field without loss of functionality, it does so.

Comment: I suspect there's an assumption behind this chain of questions: that primary constructors somehow create serializable properties, or change the fact fields are just implementation details. This isn't so. The first example in the `Initialize Property` section creates fields, not properties. Only `public  double Direction {get;}= Math.Atan2(dy, dx);` generates a property with a backing field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the "[Create mutable state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors#create-mutable-state)" section of the docs you linked.

> In the previous example, the primary constructor properties are accessed in a method. Therefore the compiler creates hidden fields to represent each parameter. [...]

It is also in the [draft spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/primary-constructors#semantics), where it is stated more precisely:

> If a primary constructor parameter is referenced from within an instance member, and the reference is not inside of a `nameof` argument, it is captured into the state of the enclosing type, so that it remains accessible after the termination of the constructor. A likely implementation strategy is via a private field using a mangled name. [...]

> If a primary constructor parameter is only referenced from within instance member initializers, those can directly reference the parameter of the generated constructor, as they are executed as part of it.

So in both cases, you get a private field that is initialised to the constructor's parameter. In the IL code they are named differently (so be careful when you use reflection), but in C# they are can be both accessed with the simple name `X`.

Do be careful in the first case to not also accidentally access the constructor parameter in a property/method. This causes the compiler to generate a field, *in addition* to the field you explicitly declared.

```
public class C2(int x) { 
  int X = x;
  int F() => x + 1; // suppose you meant to type "X + 1", but typed "x + 1" instead
}
```

Now there are two separate fields, one you can access with `X`, and one you can access with `x`.

Comment: I suspect `the primary constructor properties are accessed in a method.` and the fact that the `Initialize Property` examples actually show fields are behind the confusion